# How to parse a human readable time expression (NSString) into NSTimeInterval?

Tags: objective-c, parsing, time, expression

So say I have an NSString that has a human readable time expression like @"10 minutes" or @"2 hours". Is there an objective C library out there that will help me parse this into an NSTimeInterval? (Or a C library or anything else that I could easily use inside an iOS application).

I have written a method that will handle the simple cases. The simple cases above aren't too difficult and that's the direction that I will take if no one has any suggestions. But my code makes quite a bit of assumptions about the input. My code currently won't parse @"ten and a half minutes" or @"5 horas". (As always, date and time functions are always more difficult than they first appear.)

I've done some searching on Google, Stack Exchange, and GitHub, but the only things I've found so far are for parsing dates (not time intervals) and for parsing ISO-8601 durations (which assume very specific input).

Comment: Someone had previously posted an answer (I'm not sure what happened to it) that said they didn't know of a library, but gave some tips on how to implement a robust method. Although appreciated, I think I have a handle on how to implement it. It would just take a lot of code to do well and I find it surprising that no one has published something that does this already.

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth, I figured I would post the code I ended up using. It doesn't really answer the question since it only handles very simple cases. For my use case it was good enough, but I'd still love to see a more robust library.

```
+ (NSTimeInterval)timeIntervalFromString:(NSString *)string {
    NSTimeInterval interval    = 0.0;
    NSError *error = NULL;
    NSString *pattern          = @"^\\s*(\\d+)\\s+(second|minute|hour|day)s?\\s*$";
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern
                                                                           options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                             error:&error];
    NSTextCheckingResult *matchResult = [regex firstMatchInString:string
                                                          options:NSMatchingAnchored
                                                            range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];

    if(matchResult != nil) {
        NSString *numberString = [string substringWithRange:[matchResult rangeAtIndex:1]];
        NSString *unitString   = [string substringWithRange:[matchResult rangeAtIndex:2]];

        if([[unitString lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"second"]) {
            interval = [numberString floatValue];
        } else if([[unitString lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"minute"]) {
            interval = [numberString floatValue] * 60;
        } else if([[unitString lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"hour"]) {
            interval = [numberString floatValue] * 3600;
        } else if([[unitString lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"day"]) {
            interval = [numberString floatValue] * 3600 * 24;
        }
    }
    return interval;
}
```